# how to compile mvc project on second project form the another computer i have?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in a computer i have asp.net mvc project (XP OS) and second computer i own win7 32bit now when i access the project from XP to win7 i got the error that

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\cpname\projname\proj\themes\xxxx' because the network BIOS command limit has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to access the project from the different computer. Have you considered source control instead of accessing via network shares ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you the problem. It appears that you're storing your project on a network share and "Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform". Store the project on a local disk (e.g. C:\spname\projname)

Comment: Please cite your comment of "Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform"